# Can not see the value of php variable

Tags: javascript, php, debugging

I have a php file, from where when a button is clicked `save_match()` runs:

```
function save_match() {
    ...
    $.post('url2', {elements: elements});
    ...
}
```

and runs another php file, which has these:

```
<?php
    $tok = 1024;
    if($_POST['elements'])
    {
            echo '<script>foo("'.$tok.'") </script>';  
    ...
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(p1) {
        //alert(p1);
         document.write("|"+p1+"|");
        }     
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason I do this, is because with `echo` I can't see nothing. Well not that now I see something more.

I have opened the `url2` too in a new tab. However, after I press the button in url1 and I go to the tab of the second url, there is nothing changed. I refresh it, but still, nothing is changed!

What can I do? I need this for debugging.

Comment: you're echoing your `script` block outside of the `html`.. try echoing it before the closing `</body>` tag.. that way not only is it within the document.. its also after you've defined the `foo` function

Comment: _"The reason I do this, is because with echo I can't see nothing. Well not that now I see something more."_ DAFUQ

Comment: @haxxxton nothing happened. AbraCadaver, the truth. ;p

Comment: what value is `$_POST['elements']`.. if you are posting "0" your if statement will fail.. you should is `isset($_POST['elements'])`

Comment: I am sure I go into the if statement. Maybe I did not get your first comment good @haxxxton. I moved '<html> <body>' to the top of the file.

Comment: @G.Samaras are you expecting that when you post on the first url, that it automatically appears on the second url (in a different tab)? as this is not how this php/javascript combination will work.. you'll need to look at doing something with either a database or using something like socket.io to pass data in realtime between pages

Comment: In the first url I click the button and the `save_match()` is called. In the second url I except `foo()` to run and somehow show me the value of `$tok`. @haxxxton

Comment: your current solution will not do this. JS and PHP alone would be very difficult to implement with what you want. $_POST data is sent up to the server. and is then available to be rendered down when the page loads in the resulting request. Your second page has already been rendered from the server, so is no longer communicating with the server looking for this new post data. The simplest solution i can think of would be to save your $_POST data to a database, and have your second page ping the database for new entries every second (or slower).

Comment: @haxxxton, can you provide an example by making an answer?

Comment: When using AJAX it's a best practice to just handle data with PHP and `echo json_encode($assocArray);` the results, so you're dealing with a JavaScript Object back on the Client as the argument to your AJAX `success` function. Also, be aware that `$.post()` is Asynchronous, so don't expect a return value from `save_match` to come out of the `post` `success` function, without using a while loop to make sure the Asynchronous action has already occurred.

Comment: So what should I do @PHPglue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do to see value of the token.

1. Remove all html tags from your php files as they are not required.
2. Remove the function foo. and the scripts
3. Change your code to following.

   ```
   <?php
      if (isset($_POST['elements'] && $_POST['elements']))
         echo $tok;
         .....
   ```
4. Update your javascript to:

   ```
    function save_match() {
       ...
       $.post('url2', {elements: elements}, function($token) {
            console.log($token); // will print your token in javascript console
       });
       ...
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      $tok = 1024;
      if(isset($_POST['elements']))
      {
          echo $tok;
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should be working. Make sure doctype and all the rest is set and the variable elements in POST is also set. Maybe the if function just always fails because there is no elements set.

For what you are trying to do u don't really need javascript.

Comment: It is not. see my question please.

Answer (score 0):

Example of function that waits for Asynchronous action:

```
function save_match(){
  var somethingToReturn, pushTo = [];
  $.post('url2.php', {saveMatch:1, simple:'column_value_here', anotherProp:'Example'}, function(phpComesBackHere){
    $.each(phpComesBackHere, function(i, o){
      pushTo.push(o.object_property);
    });
    somethingToReturn = pushTo;
  });
  while(1){
    if(somethingToReturn){
      return somethingToReturn;
    }
  }
}
```

On url2.php its like:

```
<?php
include 'secure_database_connection.php'; $db = db(); // function db is returning `new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');`
if(isset($_POST['saveMatch'])){
  if(+$_POST['saveMatch'] === 1){
    if(isset($_POST['simple'], $_POST['anotherProp'])){
      if($qry = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column={$_POST['simple']}")){
        if($qry->num_rows > 0){
          while($r = $qry->fetch_object()){
            $returnArray[] = array('object_property' => $r->your_property_here, 'anotherProp' => $r->and_another_property);               
          }
          echo json_encode($returnArray);
        }
        $qry->free();
      }
    }
    else{
      // simple and/or anotherProp hack
    }
  }
  else{
    // saveMatch hack
  }
}
elseif(isset($_POST['somethingElse'])){
  // this could be separate $.post on same page
}
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not really like the busy waiting there, but I appreciate it.

Comment: Should return pretty quick.